# Python/Pandas: Calculating RMS in sections

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What is the best way to calculate the RMS of a column in sections in python/pandas. Here is a example for a better understanding what I mean:

| index | x | x_rms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 2.55 |
| 2 | 10 |  |
| 3 | 22 | 17.09 |
| ... | ... | ... |

So 2.55 is the RMS of 2 and 3, 17.09 is the RMS of 10 and 22 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following will work

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([2,3,10,22], columns=["x"])

def rms(a, b):
    # return round(np.sqrt((a**2+b**2)/2), 2) # for only two decimals
    return np.sqrt((a**2+b**2)/2)

df["rms"] = [rms(df.loc[idx-1,"x"], val["x"]) if idx%2 != 0 else np.nan 
             for idx, val in df.iterrows()]
```

**output**

```
    x   rms
0   2   NaN
1   3   2.549510
2   10  NaN
3   22  17.088007
```

**EDIT** regarding comment

if your index is a date you should do this to have the same output

```
values = [2,3,10,22]
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=len(values), freq='D') 
df = pd.DataFrame([2,3,10,22], columns=["x"], index=tidx)

def rms(a, b):
    # return round(np.sqrt((a**2+b**2)/2), 2) # for only two decimals
    return np.sqrt((a**2+b**2)/2)

df = df.reset_index()
df["rms"] = [rms(df.loc[idx-1,"x"], val["x"]) if idx%2 != 0 else np.nan 
             for idx, val in df.iterrows()]
df.set_index("index")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq. I have forgotten to mention that in my case the index is a DatetimeIndex.

Comment: @Horst-Jackson update the answer for a timestamp index